# Dephi XE7 Component Icons not working

Tags: delphi, icons, components, delphi-xe7

I am in the process of moving a number components I have written from XE2 to XE7. All these components have individual icons. The icons are contained in a .dcr file in each component project file along with the pascal source file(s), the source of the .bpl file references the .dcr file. All the component icons show correctly in the relevant XE2 component palette folder.

When I install one of these components into XE7, the component icon does not appear in the component palette. If I close XE7 and re-open it, the component ICON now appears in the component palette.

If I then install another of these components into XE7, once again the new component icon does not appear in the palette.

If I restart XE7, the new component icon will probably appear in the component palette, but the previous icon will now be missing (this behaviour varies from time to time).

So, as I install further components, some the components icons sometimes appear correctly, but most are missing.

The components work fine, it is just that the component icon is missing.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Thanks in anticipation - Jim

Comment: Maybe try to add all the components in one project and then install them all at once!

Comment: I have has a similar problem. If I find the answer, I'll post here